# how to randomly display only one 1 image from the array of object

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, visual-web-developer

how to display single image randomly?
I have created an array of objects where the images are been added now I need to display those images randomly but one at once and it will change in the next reload.

```
const index= () => {
  let gifGallery=[
    {
      src:'./Images/1.gif',
      value:1
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/2.gif',
      value:2
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/3.gif',
      value:3
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/4.gif',
      value:4
    },
   

  ]
  return (
   <>
   <h1>Gif Gallery</h1>
   <div>
    {
     what should be the logic here?????
    }
   </div>
   </>
  )
}
```

Comment: use Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4550505/getting-a-random-value-from-a-javascript-array

Comment: const currentImage = gifGallery[Math.floor(Math.random() * gifGallery.length)];

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
function getRandomImage(arr) {
  const length = arr.length;
  const randomIndex = Math.floor(length * Math.random())
  return arr[randomIndex]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can get a random value from an array of objects and use it in your return method.

let gifGallery=[
    {
      src:'./Images/1.gif',
      value:1
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/2.gif',
      value:2
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/3.gif',
      value:3
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/4.gif',
      value:4
    },
  ]
  var randomObject = gifGallery[Math.floor(Math.random() * gifGallery.length)];
  return (
   <>
   <h1>Gif Gallery</h1>
   <div>
    <image src={randomObject.src} alt={randomObject.value} />
   </div>
   </>
  )
```

Comment: page is blank no images shown

Comment: You can check example in codepan which I have created for you > https://codepen.io/sedhal/pen/KKodMVw

Answer (score 0):

use `Math.floor()`, you can see the docs on [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor), I hope this would be helpful. thanks

```js
let gifGallery=[
    {
      src:'./Images/1.gif',
      value:1
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/2.gif',
      value:2
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/3.gif',
      value:3
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/4.gif',
      value:4
    },
   

  ]
  
const randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * gifGallery.length)
console.log(randomImage)
```

```
const index= () => {
  let gifGallery=[
    {
      src:'./Images/1.gif',
      value:1
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/2.gif',
      value:2
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/3.gif',
      value:3
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/4.gif',
      value:4
    },
   

  ]

  const randomImage = Math.floor(Math.random() * gifGallery.length)

  return (
   <>
   <h1>Gif Gallery</h1>
   <div>
    <img src={gifGallery[randomImage].src} />
   </div>
   </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to generate a random number between 0 and the last index of your image array. Ideally you'd store it in a `useState`, so that you can change it when you want (say for instance you have a button that says "get random GIF").

You would need a function like this one to generate the `randomIdx`:

```js
const getRandomIdx = ()  => Math.floor(Math.random() * gifGallery.length)
```

The way to create such functions is well explained in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random).

You would then put in your JSX an `<img />` tag, whose `src` attribute is stored in the src property of the object at `gifGallery[randomIdx]`.

```
  const gifGallery=[
    {
      src:'./Images/1.gif',
      value:1
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/2.gif',
      value:2
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/3.gif',
      value:3
    },
    {
      src:'./Images/4.gif',
      value:4
    },
 
  ]

const getRandomIdx = ()  => Math.floor(Math.random() * gifGallery.length)

const App = () => {
    const [randomIdx, setRandomIdx] = useState(getRandomIdx())
        
    return (
           <>
               <h1>Gif Gallery</h1>
            <div>
                <img src={gifGallery[randomIdx].src} />
            </div>
            <p>Idx : {randomIdx}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setRandomIdx(getRandomIdx())}>
                get another random one
            </button>
        </>
    )
}
```

you have a working exemple in [this React Playground](https://reactplayground.vercel.app/#N4IglgdgJgpgHgOgFYGcQC5wFsAOB7AJwBcACAQRxxIDMC8sSByBAegp2RTkYB0IxchUgCUYAQwDGpWvSYFxU3v0HESwEhPliiMYXjykAvjToNGWqQFoo9FhIA2YGBCJK+EvBBSkPLsZBgCEgBeEhsJAFcsZyIEAHMYIgBRexholwAhAE8ASSgACnN9VwBKd09vEjoDEI0tHT0DfN8ifwhAsohq2PloQPy+EhJRSVjNcR0UtJiBiCGhkakEAGUiAjApAFk8WAAaQfmICPt7fbn5xbH6mCn0onz2TqHOkpBdkHZOOAxsfFVL3ZqEgRFAwVbaGAkYwyBg8EAWIhwgDcfHKXlIcTA1AA4mIToEsrUANoHYAHIYoAgSdAkOEACyIRBwKHQLBYOA2KCiCBwdIMeBQLDAUBYAAYWAAmUXigDM0rhZ3mJAAbniIjAaQBGRVQnVk84Uqk0+mM5ms9mc7m8-mC4UsTWS6UsOWihXklVqjUkCU6wx692U6m0kAMpkstkciRcrA8vlEAVCkWa8VS2Xyt7u1X2dU0mW+-0GkiB40h03hi1Rq1xhN25Mpp0ut2FrM5kgAFnzfAAuiiIGjKgkiMIxNB6Hk4LV8iUQgA+EibbR0hDUez6Aj5BdEJcEEc2LBTkgAKhImJxeNSBCyCFSEDiW5Kvf7pHYk+nwTn+qGvkqRJ3o6w46AqCQ67mOUBwF2tQgmCrQ6Pkg7Dv+45Tg+qLnPIRARAQcyzEqAA8M7ukMeF0pqM7YliJC4vil54SwpGEYWxFQGAyqMUq+ECHERZUsEwCntRF5ZL+oEAeBXYIIGxgsOxHF0SxbFESQeE4DO44kDSwB-nu46GHRqlKXhABGESMp4JCeAAwo4EgANZ8Qe75FokiE6eB8EuaJyElCUhiyRxJ6JCQI4GHSgRVKJFntIZLAmWZED+cpMkHKhECGI+7RwH8pCwNQYjHM+lC9iAhhAA)